# setText if IP isReachable = true

Tags: java, android, textview, settext

I will set two outputs. The first one if I can reach the ip adress the other one if I cannot reach it.

```
TextView server_statusTextView = findViewById(R.id.server_status);
try {
        if (InetAddress.getByAddress("1.1.1.1".getBytes()).isReachable(1000)) {
            server_statusTextView.setText("online");
        } else {
            server_statusTextView.setText("offline");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, it does not write anything into my TextView.
How I get this working?

Comment: The only scenario I can imagine where the text does not end up being `online` or `offline` is that your call to `InetAddress.getByAddress` is throwing an exception, and the entire `if` block is not executing.  Can you step through your code with a debugger to give us more information here?

Comment: In the debug log I get `java.net.UnknownHostException: addr is of illegal length`. I think this is the problem, but what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have never personally used the `InetAddress.getByAddress` API, but from your code and comments, it looks like an exception is being thrown, and the entire `if` block is not executing.  If you logically equate that exception with being offline, then you may set the text to `offline` should an exception happen:

```
TextView server_statusTextView = findViewById(R.id.server_status);

try {
    if (InetAddress.getByAddress("1.1.1.1".getBytes()).isReachable(1000)) {
        server_statusTextView.setText("online");
    } else {
        server_statusTextView.setText("offline");
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // if the call to getByAddress fails, then consider the state to be offline
    server_statusTextView.setText("offline");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Okay, now I get an output. But the output is offline while I am able to connect to the ip adress. 

I have nothing against another solution when my is not possible working.

Comment: Well here's the thing, logically speaking if, for whatever reason (and again I don't know this API well) you cannot _ascertain_ that the address is reachable, even if it might really be reachable, then perhaps your app should be reporting `offline`.

Comment: @Hannes This isn't preventing the exception you're getting, it's just saying you're offline when you get it rather than nothing

Comment: Yeah, I understand this problem. But in other Activitys and Fragments I am able to parse and download stuff from the same adress which I want call here. And if I am not able to parse or download something because the file is not available I add an output "not available". Next to this I want to check if the server is online (or if the app is able to connect to it).

Comment: @Hannes Then handle TimeOut exception or a non 2xx or 3xx status code accordingly. I'm not sure checking IP addresses is really considered "safe". At least for most online file sharing services

Comment: I need to save as much data as possible. If I connect to the file and it is available it needs much data.

Comment: @Hannes You are veering off topic from your original question.  If my answer (and the duplicate link) don't fix your problem, then it's time to open a new question IMO.